# How to develop data visualization for time series database?

Tags: graph, frontend, data-visualization, data-analysis, influxdb

I have a time series database for which I have to build a front-end. The front-end needs to contain some panels and graph on the basis of the data provided to it from database. Can anyone suggest me a tool which I can use to build the front-end and then connect with the database (InfluxDB)?

Answer (score 0):

You have two popular options as follows:

- **Chronograf**: The 'C' letter of the TICK Stack. It offers a complete dashboarding solution for quickly visualising the data that you have stored in InfluxDB. You can run queries and build alerts easily. It is very simple to use and includes several templates. However, it does not have plugin support to extend its visualisation capabilities. For example, there is no a pie chart and traffic light visualisation out-of-the-box.
- **Grafana**: This is the other popular option. It provides the similar beautiful dashboarding capabilities as Chronograf, but in contrast, you can use it to visualise the data that not only stored in InfluxDB but also other data stores such as Prometheus, Elasticsearch, Graphite, etc. It allows you to install community developed plugins to extend visualisation capabilities of the solution.

In summary, both are very good and can be easily integrated to InfluxDB. I find Grafana more flexible and feature rich. Grafana is used more widely so you may find answers for specific questions easier. I also recommend that you have a look at issues in both solutions' GitHub account before coming to a conclusion.